# Batch: Find values in text file and add new lines

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I have a text file that has the following lines multiple times:

```
REPORT TOTALS          ###.##    ##
***********NEW REPORT************
```

"REPORT TOTALS" is static, however, any characters thereafter changes.
"***********NEW REPORT************" is static.

Trying to create a script that puts a new line in between, however, problem being wildcards do not work with EQU Command:
   "REPORT TOTALS*"

The following is the base of my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal

set inputfile=Test.txt
set outputfile=Test_OutPut.txt

(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%inputFile%") do (
   echo(%%a
   if "%%a" equ "REPORT TOTALS*" (
      echo.
      echo.
   )
)) > "%outputfile%"

ECHO/
ECHO Done!
```

Expected result would be:

```
REPORT TOTALS          ###.##    ##


***********NEW REPORT************
```

Comment: Concerning your `echo` problem: change `echo %%a` to `echo(%%a`. For the other problem, I'd place another `for /F` loop around the `if` condition: `for /F "tokens=1-2" %%b in ("%%a") do (if "%%b %%c"=="REPORT TOTALS" ...)`...

Comment: That certainly corrected my echo problem, thank you!

Comment: @aschipfl Not certain I follow your suggested:

 For the other problem, I'd place another for /F loop around the if condition: for /F "tokens=1-2" %%b in ("%%a") do (if "%%b %%c"=="REPORT TOTALS" ...)

Comment: I was referring to your "wildcard" problem: the additional `for /F` loop splits off the first two white-space-separated words from the current line to compare them with your fixed two-word text... (Make sure to use `echo/` rather than `echo.`!)

Comment: OK, smelling what you're cooking.  However, breaking my batch when I put the suggested code in.  Think I am missing potentially where within the batch.

Comment: My code suggestion is intended to replace your whole `if` block (including the related opening and closing parentheses), and the `...` is just meant to be the conditionally executes code (like `echo/&echo/`)...

Comment: Maybe easier to insert the blank lines before `***********NEW REPORT************` (completely static line) instead of after `REPORT TOTALS *` (partial static line)?

Comment: Could not agree more! However, uncertain how to add lines ABOVE this static line.

Comment: Easy. Move the `echo(%%a` line BELOW the (adapted) `if` block.

Comment: Yes! Excellent!!!

THANK YOU! WE ARE NOW GOOD TO GO!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nesting another [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop), I would just use [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) to check for lines beginning with `REPORT TOTALS` :

```bat
@If Exist "Test.txt" (>"Test_OutPut.txt" (For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=]" %%A In (
            '^""%__AppDir__%find.exe" /V /N ""^<"Test.txt"^" 2^>NUL'
        ) Do @(Echo="%%B"|>NUL "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /BRIC:"\"REPORT TOTALS "
            If ErrorLevel 1 (Echo=%%B) Else Echo=%%B&Echo=&Echo=)))
```